# Finding corresponding hex bolts and keys for electric guitar bridge

Tags: electric-guitar, maintenance, repair

The guitar is Washburn G5V, I suppose it's around 25 years old. It's a great sounding guitar I'd like to keep for a long time, and there's a problem with the vintage Floyd Rose bridge - it has these hex bolts that lock the strings in and they're all worn out and I'm having huge difficulties changing the strings cause my hex key can't screw the bolts out.

Sample bridge with the bolts in:

[image: Floyd rose example with bolts]

Sample bolt extracted from the bridge:

[image: My hex key and a bolt]

Dimensions:

2mm thickness
12mm length (with head top)
10mm length (without head top)

No local shops have bolts of the corresponding width, and I haven't been able to find these online for purchase. Where can I get new set of bolts for installment? Also, the local guitar repairman had no clue. I'm lucky to have gotten the hex key from a nice guy in a guitar shop, their guess was "You'll never find this for purchase. Better off buying a new bridge."

Can this be ordered from Floyd Rose directly as bridge parts?

Comment: Even if you could find that for purchase, +1 on getting a new bridge. You might pull one of your pickup ring screws and find a matching ones at a hardware store and replace those also, just to keep things nice and un-rusted.

Comment: Why don't you speak to Washburn about it. They may be more than willing to help keep one of their oldies going.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct name for these screws are "Metric Socket Head Cap / Allen Screws (DIN 912)". Google this for your area.

Here in the Uk M2 X 12 are aprox £5 per hundred.

Are you sure of your dimensions as Floyd Rose being a USA company the may be using American standard threads. The following may be used.

1-72 UNF 1.854mm or 2-64 UNF 2.184mm

1-64 UNC 1.854mm or 2-56 UNC 2.184mm

Comment: +1 for 'non-metric'. American stuff is (and was) usually imperial. Strings are still quoted as 'thous'!

Comment: another +1 for Imperial… there'd be at least one more for [Whitworth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Standard_Whitworth) & derivatives… no wonder you can never find a spanner to fit… took me years to find a socket driver to fit my Rikki truss-rods & still have enough play to actually turn them.

Comment: @Tetsujin  Actually for small sizes under 1/4 inch us British used to use [**BA**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Association_screw_threads)  series screws. 8 or 0BA is near 2mm.

Comment: I'm glad we went metric ;)

Comment: I've found them finally on ebay UK. Gonna order them. I'm from Croatia so no way I could have found it here locally.

Comment: @AnonymousLettuce Be careful fitting them just in case they are not the same.Double check all dimensions. Hold the threads of the new ones against the old ones and hold them up to the light to ensure they are the same. Or check the pitch is 0.4mm ie 10 threads == 4mm. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Unless you find a place that stocks vintage parts, I'd suggest going to your local hardware store, as they may have these. Some may even be able to fabricate them for you.

That said, the whole trem looks like it needs some serious TLC - you could do as the guitar tech suggested and replace it.